# maven-metadata.xml for a group very slow

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-metadata

What are `maven-metadata.xml` for "groups"? How can we influence whether Maven loads `maven-metadata.xml` for a group or for a particular repository? And why is loading them for groups so incredibly slow?

```
/content/groups/public/<groupId-artifactId>/maven-metadata.xml
```

takes ~22s to load.

```
/content/repositories/internal-repository-release/<groupId-artifactId>/maven-metadata.xml
```

takes 32ms.

There was a related [bug in Nexus 1.9.2](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4464) but we're now on 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Getting-maven-metadata-xml-for-a-group-very-slow-tp5768650p5768794.html) I got on the `nexus-user` mailing list:

"[Setting up routing](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html) in Nexus properly should help."